# When using hyperref, references links doesn't work and turn into (??)

Tags: hyperref, citing

When I use `hyperref`, my links just turn into `(??)`.

Reproducible code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,twoside]{article}



%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}  %My package for citations
\usepackage{hyperref}          %if i remove this, the references works

\begin{document}


\section{Intro}

According to \cite{test}

\bibliography{ref}


\end{document}
```

And I have a file (`ref.bib`) with  this:

```
@misc{test,
  author = {Bryce Graham},
  title = {Hydrological Modelling:
How and Why it is Used},
  year = 2009,
  url = {https://dpipwe.tas.gov.au/Documents/Hydrological%20modelling_how%20and%20why%20it%20is%20used.pdf},
  urlaccessdate = {08/07/2021}
}
```

Compiler: XeLaTeX

Comment: well if you look into the document of abntex2cite and search for hyperref, you can see that it requires that hyperref is loaded before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

According to \cite{test}

\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Technically correct, but you might want to explain what you changed,...